# Closed sets and sequences in Metric spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $x \subset X$ is a closed set, the sequence {$ {x_j}$}${ } \subset F$ and $x \in X$. Show that if $x_j \to x$ as $j \to \infty$, then $x \in F$

Okay so I really don't know where to start with this question, It is part of a chapter on metric spaces in a complex analysis course. Would I show that the sequence {$ {x_j}$}$\in B_n(x)$? Would this be sufficient to show that $x \in F$?

Any help or solutions would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think this is true.  Let $X = \{ 0 }\$, then $X$ is a closed set.  Now let $F = {\ \frac{1}{n} \}$.  Now $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ then $x_n \to x$ but clearly $0 \notin F$.

Comment: it is true it is in my coursebook..

Comment: I don't think it is true. Counter Example X={1/n}$\cup${0}. It is closed set.Take F={1/n}. Clearly 0 does not belong to F.

Comment: are you sure you are reading it properly? it is a in my coursebook so it cant be wrong...

Comment: You did not write the problem statement correctly. Change "Suppose $x\in X$" to "Suppose $F\subset X$".

Comment: sorry my mistake i have changed it now!!

Comment: How does your text/class define a closed set?  Is it the complement of an open set, or are you working from some other (presumably equivalent) definition?  Also, you still haven't made the correction recommended by David Mitra.  Your first sentence should begin "Suppose $F\subset X$ is a closed set..."

Comment: a set F is closed if its compliment is open

Comment: so a set F is open if its compliment is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is true.  Here is a counter-example, let $X$ be the set containing the element $0$.  Then $X$ is clearly closed.  Now let $F$ be any sequence $(x_n)$ of positive terms that tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Then clearly $0 \notin F$.

Comment: error in question please see edit